# what is the use of express-http-context in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

i cant find the documentation for bindemitter in express-http-context.what is the use of this particular method?

```
 httpContext.ns.bindEmitter(req);
  httpContext.ns.bindEmitter(res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindEmitter` is a function provided by one of `express-http-context`'s dependencies, namely `cls-hooked` and is described on their [documentation](https://github.com/Jeff-Lewis/cls-hooked):

> Bind an EventEmitter to a namespace. [...]
>
> The most likely time you'd want to use this is when you're using
> Express or Connect and want to make sure your middleware execution
> plays nice with CLS, or are doing other things with HTTP listeners [...]

So it basically allows you to ensure that `req/res` will be within the scope of the namespace that `express-http-context` has created and that this context is not lost.